# Infinite loop? Eclipse stops answering when I test run

Tags: eclipse, infinite-loop, blackjack

This is my first post, so I hope I'm doing this right. I'm currently working on a very simple black jack.

When I test my program (as seen below), nothing comes out, but eclipse just keeps working forever unless i terminate. I looked up the problem, and it seems it probably was an infinite loop. After messing around with the code a bit more, I still have the problem.

Although I'm 99% sure that the "while (sum < 16)" loop is causing the problem, I don't see why it would continue forever, since the sum should get larger and larger.

Thanks for the help.

```html
public class DrawCardFromDeck 
{
 
 public static double GetRandomNumber (double Range)
 //generates a random number from 0 to range-1
 {

  double Number;
  Number = Math.random()*Range;
  Number = Math.floor(Number);
  return Number;
 
 }

 public static int value(int cardID)
 //stores values for each "card ID number"
 {

  int [] cardValue = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};
  return cardValue[cardID];
  
 }

 public static String suit(int cardID)
 //stores suits for each "card ID number"
 {
  String [] suit = {"of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs", "of hearts", "of spades", "of Diamonds", "of Clubs"};
  return suit[cardID];
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  int sum = 0;
  int indexPosition;
  int cardsDrawn = 0;
  
  boolean [] cardCounter = new boolean [52]; 
  for (indexPosition = 0; indexPosition < cardCounter.length-1; indexPosition++)
   cardCounter[indexPosition] = true;
  //keeps track of which "card ID numbers" have been generated

  int [] cardID = new int [10];
  //creates a space in which to save the card ID's
  
  while (sum < 16)
  //Generates random cards while sum of their values is less than 16. 
  //Also makes sure each card is only drawn once by referencing the cardCounter array above. 
  {
   
   if (cardCounter[indexPosition] == true)
   {
    cardID[indexPosition] = (int) GetRandomNumber(52);
    cardCounter[indexPosition] = false; //set equal to false so its not drawn again
    sum += value(cardID[indexPosition]); //add to the sum
    cardsDrawn++; //count cards drawn (will be used later)
    
   } 
    
  }
  
  
  if (sum > 21) //if bust, reduce values of aces by 10
  {
   for (indexPosition = 0; indexPosition < cardsDrawn; indexPosition++)
   {
    
    if(cardID[indexPosition] % 14 == 0)
    {
     sum -= 10;
    } 
    
   }
   
   if (sum>21) //if still bust, output bust
    System.out.println("Bust");
   
  }
  
  
  if (sum<=21) 
  //Else, print the cards that were drawn and the sum. 
  {
   
   System.out.println("Your hand: ");
   for(indexPosition = 0; indexPosition < cardsDrawn; indexPosition++)
   {
    System.out.println(value(cardID[indexPosition]) + suit(cardID[indexPosition]));
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
   
  }
  
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that indexPosition is not set. Since this variable is used as index the same card will be used which is only added once.

Actually I would expect indexPosition due the iteration loop above would result in beyond the last card, but probably this is not true.

Comment: Thank you! How could I forget, haha. 
Now I have the problem that it only outputs bust instead, though, but hopefully I will figure it out... Thanks again. ^^

Comment: You're welcome ... don't forget to upvote/accept the answer (this will make sure next time are more willingly to answer your questions).